# SOLVED Raspberry Pi 4 WiFi and Ethernet stop working after a ribbon cable plugged in to custom HAT

Tags: wifi, power-supply, ethernet

I have been struggling with a strange issue where as soon as I plug a ribbon cable into a custom designed HAT (with nothing connected on the other end), the WiFi and Ethernet temporarily go down.

My custom HAT consists of a 5V DC/DC converter to step down 10S Li-Ion battery voltages to 5V based on the SiC471 (switching at ~300kHz). The ribbon cable consists of 5V, 24V (from TL783), Vbat, I2C,3 gpio and GND.

I tested the situation by first starting a ping to the Pi (via both ethernet and WiFi), and then plugging in the ribbon cable. As soon as I plug it in, the pings stop.
If I unplug it, the pings return along with all of the lost pings with very high latency.

I measured the voltages with a scope and they were always good (~4.96V on the 5V rail).

Assuming it was noise being exacerbated by the large ribbon cable now being an antenna, I created a new wiring assembly but this time with 6-core shielded cable, but the issue still remained.

I'm still assuming it is a noise issue, but if it was, why would it affect both ethernet and WiFi simultaneously?

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers,
K

EDIT: I checked var/log/syslog and messages and turns out it appears to be a hardware interrupt related to GPIO23.
When I force GPIO23 to 3.3V on the ribbon, the processor comes out of halt. Any ideas on how to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was due to a combination of switching noise from the DC/DC converter, and a ROS service running on the Pi monitoring GPIO23 and running callbacks so frequently it used up most of the processor time.